# varImp in caret "generating" thousands of variables

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a model like the following:

```
model

Random Forest 

 56 samples
100 predictors
  2 classes: 'control', 't1d' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  ROC         Sens        Spec      
     2  0.08673469  0.10714286  0.28571429
   104  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.03571429
  5499  0.00000000  0.03571429  0.00000000

ROC was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

It shows that I only have 100 predictors. However, when I run varImp, this is the output.

```
rf variable importance

  only 20 most important variables shown (out of 5500)

                 Overall
v720.004520377    100.00
v950.0010273908    91.59
v830.0005474310    88.41
v760.00021678889   86.73
v30.011279394      85.48
v310.002027226     84.64
v600.0030823047    82.53
v70.02515785       82.40
v110.002849240     78.08
v740.004275572     75.37
v170.00045555545   74.44
v170.00042719287   73.48
v70.01859216       72.23
v190.01569173      70.90
v700.013340430     70.70
v330.02143915      70.46
v560.013864934     69.61
v340.014476069     69.32
v810.002786661     69.18
v100.008557477     67.65
```

What do the numbers after the decimal mean? My features were named "v1" through "v100." Why is this saying I had 5500 variables?

If you have any ideas why the output looks like this I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe many of the variables were factors with many levels? Random forest converts factors to dummy variables if I am not mistaken. If this is not the case you could provide the first 30 rows with `dput`?

Comment: @missuse That was it! Thanks!